# setting Slider extender minimum and maximum value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a slider whose minimum and maximum value has to be taken from a label

Following is the code

```
  <asp:SliderExtender ID="TextBox3_SliderExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="TextBox3"
                       BoundControlID="TextBox4"  TargetControlID="TextBox3" EnableHandleAnimation="true" 
                       Maximum='<%# Math.Round(((double)lblMax.Text),0) %>' Minimum='<%# Math.Round((double)lblMin.Text,0) %>' Orientation="Horizontal" Steps="100" />
```

the error in above code is cannot convert type 'string to 'double'

how can i set maximum value from label named lblMax as Maximum for slider extender
(Note : - lblMax contain integer value)

```
 Maximum='<%# Math.Round(((double)lblMax.Text),0) %>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  minimum and maximum value can be set throught code as

TextBox3_SliderExtender.Minimum = int.Parse(lblMin.Text.ToString());
  TextBox3_SliderExtender.Maximum = int.Parse(lblMax.Text.ToString());

that will pick the value from the label and we can assign dynamically the value to tha label

thax 4 the help

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly cast a string to a double. You're looking for `double.Parse()`.

Comment: the above solution does not generate any error but it is not working , it is taking the default minimum and maximum value as 0 to 100